# After updating row in a DataGrid control, how can I make the page jump back down to that row?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I am using a data grid in an ASP.NET page to display a data table.

I am not using paging.

If I click "update" the page reloads, changing that specific row to update mode. The problem is that I have to scroll back down to the row to enter the data. I want it to automatically jump down to that row.

The same thing happens when submitting the update. It reloads, but stays at the top of the page. Instead, I want it to jump back down to the row that was just updated.

Update: adding code block.   I can get the  tag to output in each row of the data grid, but not sure where or how to do the script part...

The Form:

```
 <form id="FORMNAME" runat="server">
```

The DataGrid:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="dataGrid" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="RESORTS" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server">
        <Columns>
             <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="" />

            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="KEY" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="True"  />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="NAME">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HREFID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    NAME:<br />
                    <asp:textbox id="NAME" text='<%# Bind("NAME") %>' runat="server"/>
                    <br />
                    SITE:<br />
                    <asp:textbox id="Textbox1" text='<%# Bind("URL") %>' runat="server"/>
                    <br />
                    LOGO:<br />
                    <asp:textbox id="LOGO_URL" text='<%# Bind("LOGO_URL") %>' runat="server"/>                    
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HREFID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> 

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parent" SortExpression="PARENT_NAME">
                <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PARENT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PARENT_NAME") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>   


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Logo Image" SortExpression="IMGLOGOURL" ItemStyle-CssClass="logoCell">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IMGURL") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("IMGURL") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>                  


             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NOTES" SortExpression="NOTES" ItemStyle-CssClass="textAreaCell">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                  <br />
                  PARENT:<br />
                  <asp:DropDownList ID="PARENT_NAME" runat="server" DataSourceID="RESORTS" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PARENT_ID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
                <br />NOTES:<br />
                    <asp:textbox id="NOTES" text='<%# Bind("NOTES") %>' Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NOTESTA") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>     

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Try: MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" on the page directive above, it should work!

Comment: Thanks, but it fails in every browser but IE.

Answer (score 0):

If MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" doesnt work for you then add a anchor to each row and use javascript to navigate to it.

e.g:

```
<a name="row1" />
```

and use javascript like

```
window.location.hash="#row1"
```

Comment: @Vaibhav Garg - I can implement the <a name="row1" /> but i am not sure how/where to implement the javascript. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I spoke too soon, it turns out i don't understand how to properly implement the a tag also

Comment: It should be easy if you are using templates. just use the Container;s Index property. show us some example code and I can advice better. you can emmit script in ur onupdate event like: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "scrollscript", "window.location.hash='#row'" & RowId.ToString(), True)

Comment: you can use a template column like this : <asp:TemplateColumn><ItemTemplate><a name='<%#"row" & Container.ItemIndex%>' /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateColumn> or just include the <a..> part in another template column.

Comment: I was able to print out the <a NAME="ROWID22"></a>, etc. Thanks for the help.

I'm still stuck on the part about how to dynamically include the javascript block...     so,   i posted my example code up in the original post...

Comment: use this code(VB) inside your updated event: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "scrollscript", "window.location.hash='#ROWID" & EditedUpdatedRowId.ToString() & "';", True) 'where EditedUpdatedRowId is the ID of the row being edited

Comment: Vaibhav, i still don't understand where to put this code...  any pointers you can give would be appreciated